# Defining VSTS Field only when Value of field is not Set

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a need to set the value of a date field when the value of substate field changes only if no value already exists in the date field. Is it possible?

```
<FIELD refname="MyCorp.StateDate" name="Date Of Last State Change" type="DateTime">
    <WHENCHANGED field="MyCorp.State">
        <COPY from="clock" /> ** AND do this only of MyCorp.StateDate != Empty **
    </WHENCHANGED>
</FIELD>
```

I read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194966.aspx but I am not able to find any way to implement what I need from the WIT language definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio Team Services, add rules to work item is not supported now.

If you are using on-premise TFS, you can add field action in state transition, for example:

```
<TRANSITION from="New" to="Committed">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Commitment made by the team" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="starain.ScrumStarain.StateChageDate">
              <WHEN field="starain.ScrumStarain.StateChageDate" value="">
                <COPY from="clock" />
              </WHEN>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
```